# CakePHP2 posting empty at add.ctp

Tags: forms, cakephp, empty-list

(EDITED)

At my `http://host/MyCake/index.php/table/add`, a form with 10 inputs (fields), when submit, I have

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 
    ERROR: null value in column "revista_id" violates not-null constraint
SQL Query: 
    INSERT INTO "fasciculos" ("created", "modified", "user_id") VALUES ('now()', 'now()', 1)
```

Well, about "Not null violation" (field `revista_id`) I try changing SQL with `ALTER COLUMN revista_id DROP NOT NULL` (remove the constraint), and change was ok, it runs!  BUT, the **problem** is: **where the other 10 fields at the SQL INSERT?*!!

Yes, when I changed, the submited data record are empty, all 10 fields was NULL.

---

I am using PostgreSQL 9.X.

I also checked with var_dump at the FasciculoController if the posted data was there, and, yes, it is there,

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Fasciculo->create();
        var_dump($this->request->data); // showing below 
        if ($this->Fasciculo->save($this->request->data)) // bug here!
                    ...
             }...
    ...}
```

The vardump have all POST data,

```
  array(1) {  
     ["Fasciculos"]=>array(11) {  
         ["other_id"]=> string(3) "540" 
         //... all data here ...
     }
  }
```

Comment: Do any of your other controller `add()` functions work?

Comment: I wonder if the name `Table` is causing some sort of reserved word problem here... but I can't seem to find `Table` being used in the CakePHP API....  It is kind of strange to use the word "table" for an actual `table` in SQL, though, right?

Comment: @summea, about 1st question, Yes, it does. About Second: sorry, I changed the original name, it is a valid name, for all applicartions (SQL and Cake).

Comment: Is "other_id" a fake name, or the actual content? Reading the error message this should be `revista_id`? Also, for debugging in CakePHP, please use the `debug()` command, which will give you a more readable output than `var_dump()`

Comment: From the info in the question, according to cake the only fields that exist in your table are `created`, `modified` and `user_id`. Cake will ignore any fields you pass to save that are not in the schema. As such what is your table schema, what is your _actual_ post data and what is your model code? "all data here" <- not helpful.

Comment: Hum... But if was a problem with Cake-Model, the index.ctp not shows all 10 fields... they are there, listing all. Where can I check it? (I think it is all scaffold)

Comment: @PeterKrauss Is there any way we could have you post your database "schema" for this particular table?

Answer (score 0):

`TABLE` is a reserved keyword in MySQL/PostgreSQL and in being a reserved keyword, I think the database might be getting confused by the `INSERT INTO table ...` part of your SQL.

There could be something else going on here as well, but it might be a good idea to try renaming your `Table` model and controller.  *(And make sure to clear the CakePHP cache files when making major changes to models, etc.)*

See: [MySQL reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), [PostgreSQL reserved keywords](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

Comment: sorry, as I commented above "... I changed the original name, it is a valid name, for all applicartions (SQL and Cake)".

Comment: @PeterKrauss Thanks again for the update.  I just had another idea about this, as well: after you changed the name of the model and controller, etc. did you make sure to clear out the cache for your CakePHP project?  Sometimes the cache will hold on to your old model names... and that last model name probably conflicted with the reserved keyword `TABLE` as discussed earlier.  What happens if you try and delete your CakePHP `cache` files?

Comment: The name naver changed, only first edit was a simplification, now I show a exact dump... I changed only the not-null, and this was ok, no-cache. I have nother version and another people try with the same results... Well, thanks your support.

Comment: @PeterKrauss Sorry that it's not working out for you, yet; we can still keep trying, though, with a little more information...

Comment: @PeterKrauss Did you ever find out the cause of the problem for this past question?

Comment: no... I am abandoning CakePHP, it not was made to run *without* mod_rewrite.

Comment: @PeterKrauss Oh, while `mod_rewrite` is important for nice URLs, CakePHP does appear to work without the need for `mod_rewrite` itself... if curious, see: [URL Rewriting](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html) and the various server differences listed for URL rewriting.